# LoaderManager.onLoadFinished is called even when the specific query doesn't match the update

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager

I have a Android app which has a Content Provider which I update frequently. To load the lists of the said data, I'm using a LoaderManager.

On the detail page, I also use a LoaderManager, but I create the CursorLoader like this:

```
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), DataProvider.POST_URI, projection, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(post_id)}, null);
```

As you can see, I'm only getting a single item from the table. When the row is updated the the `onLoadFinished` callback is updated, but, also, when other rows are added/modified to the table. It wouldn't be much of a hassle, but sometimes, it causes the whole list to get blank and redrawn, which can be frustrating for the user when it happens multiple times.

Do you know how could I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reloading is taking place because you are associating this cursor loader with the `DataProvider.POST_URI` which I assume is the one you use for your posts table. Whenever there is a change in any of the elements in this table, all the cursors with that `Uri` will be notified. If you want to receive notification of a single item you should implement a new `Uri` scheme to match just that one item. Have a look at the documentation for the [UriMatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html) class for an example. You should do something similar to the `PEOPLE` and `PEOPLE_ID` cases.

**EDIT**

You can find a good tutorial on `ContentProvider` [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html). Section 9.4 in special should be helpful in correctly implementing the `ContentProvider`.